# What are the pros and cons of docker pull and docker build from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have been playing around with docker for about a month and now I have a few images.
Recently, I want to share one of them to some other guy,
and I push that image X to my DockerHub, so that he can pull it from my repository.

However, this seems kind of a waste of time.
The total time spent here is **the time I do docker push** and **the time he do docker pull**.
If I just sent him the Dockerfile needed to build that image X, then the cost would be
**the time I write a Dockerfile**, **the time to pass a text file**, and **the time he do docker build**,
which is less than previous way since I maintain my Dockerfiles well.

So, that is my question: what are the pros/cons of these two approach?
Why Docker Inc. chose to launch a DockerHub service rather than a DockerfileHub service?

Any suggestions or answers would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you build an image from a Dockerfile and push that image to Docker Hub. During the build you download some sources and build a program. But when the build is done the sources become unavailable. Now the Dockerfile can't be used anymore but the image on Docker Hub is still working. That's a pro for Docker Hub.

But it can be a con too. For example if the sourcecode contains a terrible bug like Heartbleed or Shellshock. Then the sources get patched but the image on Docker Hub does not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the time you push image and the time you build image depend on your environment.
For example, you may prebuild a image for embedded system, but you won't want to build it on embedded system.

Docker Hub had provided an [Automated Builds](http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) feature which will fetch Dockerfile from GitHub, and build image. So you can get the Dockerfile of image from GitHub, it's not necessary to have a service for sharing `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It is really helpful but since the other answer did give the comparisons, I accept that one. Thanks anyway!